# Receiving a UDP Broadcast with openFrameworks

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, broadcast, openframeworks

I'm trying to receive and parse a packet being sent via UDP Broadcast.

The sending device is sending a broadcast on port 7331.

My receiving openframeworks program is based off of the ofxUDPManager documentation found here:

http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/ofxNetwork/ofxUDPManager.html

DiscoveryListener.h

```
class DiscoveryListener {
 public:
  DiscoveryListener();
  ~DiscoveryListener();
  void update();
  string getMessage();
 private:
  ofxUDPManager udpConnection;
  string message;
  int newMessage;
  static const int portNo = 7331;
  static const int packetSize = 76;
};
```

DiscoveryListener.cpp

```
#include "DiscoveryListener.h"

DiscoveryListener::DiscoveryListener() {
  udpConnection.Create();
  udpConnection.SetEnableBroadcast(true);
  udpConnection.BindMcast("0.0.0.0", portNo);
  udpConnection.SetNonBlocking(true);

  newMessage = 0;
}

void DiscoveryListener::update() {
  char udpMessage[packetSize];
  newMessage = udpConnection.Receive(udpMessage,packetSize);
  std::cout << "Packet size: " << newMessage << std::endl;
  printf("UDP Packet: %s", udpMessage);
}

string DiscoveryListener::getMessage() {
  if(newMessage) {
    return message;
  }
  else {
    return "No new messages.";
      }
}
```

ofApp.cpp

```
void testApp::setup(){
  listener = new DiscoveryListener();

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){
  listener->update();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){
  std::cout << "Frame Number: " << ofGetFrameNum() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Message: " << listener->getMessage();
}
```

And the output is:

```
Packet size: -1
UDP Packet:
Packet size: -1
UDP Packet:
Packet size: 76
UDP Packet:
Packet size: -1
UDP Packet:
Packet size: -1
```

So it seems like most of the time there's an error (packet size returns -1), and then about once a second (when the sending device sends its UDP Broadcast), I receive a packet of 76 bytes.  However, it doesn't print out and I can't seem to find a way to parse it.

Am I receiving the multicast wrong? Or is there something wrong with how I'm printing the byte array?

thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

UDP packets sometimes drop and don't use the TCP handshake. The degree of dropouts also depend on the traffic on your network.

Often the oF documentation is not quite up-to-date. I would recommend downloading the latest release (http://openframeworks.cc/download/) and base your dev on the examples found in the examples folder:

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/examples/addons/networkUdpReceiverExample/src/ofApp.cpp

How you parse the messages also depend on the terminator you chose for your messages. ("[/p]" in the examples)